# change the color of button when selected

Tags: android, xml

I am making an app with 3 buttons.

I have the following .xml file that has rectangular button.

Now I want to to make them so if one is selected then that button turns red while the other two remain green.

On forward action it was working properly: if i click c button and come back and click A button both are showing same red color and if i click B and after A button then also showing same color after some delay it is appearing .

How can I solve this?

XML:

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
      <solid android:color="#124a01" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="#c8ea32" />

</shape>
```

Activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {       
                    DeselectButtons();
                    EnabledButton = dynamicTextView.getId();
                    clickedid=dynamicTextView.getId();

                    dynamicTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#cf0000"));
                    dynamicTextView.setSelected(true);
                    invoiceToDisplay = null;
                    invoiceToDisplay = new ArrayList<String>();
                    text = dynamicTextView.getText().toString();
                    if(text.contains("Bill Numbers"))
                    {
                        text=text.replace("Bill Numbers","");
                    }
                    String s[] = text.split("  , ");

                    invoice = text.split("  , ");
                    System.out.println("s" + s[0]);
                    istouched=true;
                    refreshlist=1;
                    if (s.length == 1) {

                        if(s[0].contains("\n"))
                        {
                            s[0]=s[0].replace("\n","");
                        }
                        int invoice11=receiptlist.indexOf(s[0].trim());
                        String invoiceselected=invoiceList.get(invoice11);

                        tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        footerText3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        footerText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected, listView1, headerButton1);
                        invoice1 = invoiceselected;
                        invoice2 = "";
                        invoice3 = "";
                        headerButton2.setText("");
                        headerButton3.setText("");
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                                PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList2);

                        listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                                PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList2);
                        //adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext(),itemsList2,PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
                        listView3.setAdapter(adapter);


                        invnumber = "";
                    } else if (s.length == 2) {
                        if(s[0].contains("\n"))
                        {
                            s[0]=s[0].replace("\n","");
                        }

                        int invoice11=receiptlist.indexOf(s[0].trim());
                        String invoiceselected=invoiceList.get(invoice11);

                        int invoice12=receiptlist.indexOf(s[1].trim());
                        String invoiceselected1=invoiceList.get(invoice12);


                        invoice1 = invoiceselected;
                        invoice2 = invoiceselected1;
                        invoice3 = "";
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected, listView1, headerButton1);
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected1, listView2, headerButton2);
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                                PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList2);

                        listView3.setAdapter(adapter);
                        headerButton3.setText(""); footerText3.setVisibility(View.GONE); tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        invnumber = "";
                    } else if (s.length == 3) {

                        if(s[0].contains("\n"))
                        {
                            s[0]=s[0].replace("\n","");
                        }
                        int invoice11=receiptlist.indexOf(s[0].trim());
                        String invoiceselected=invoiceList.get(invoice11);

                        int invoice12=receiptlist.indexOf(s[1].trim());
                        String invoiceselected1=invoiceList.get(invoice12);

                        int invoice13=receiptlist.indexOf(s[2].trim());
                        String invoiceselected2=invoiceList.get(invoice13);



                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        invoice1 = invoiceselected;
                        invoice2 = invoiceselected1;
                        invoice3 = invoiceselected2;
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected, listView1, headerButton1);
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected1, listView2, headerButton2);
                        loadListViews(invoiceselected2, listView3, headerButton3);
                        invnumber = "";
                    } //thread.start();
                }
            });
            Button button = new Button(this);
            button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(10,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            linear.addView(dynamicTextView);
            linear.addView(button);
            count = 0;
            invoiceNumber = "";
            // invoice=null;
            billnumber = "";            
          }         
     }  
}
```

Method:

```
public void DeselectButtons() {
        for (int i = 1; i < id; i++) {

            if (EnabledButton != i) {
                if (this.findViewById(i) == null) {

                } else {

                    this.findViewById(i).setBackgroundColor(
                            Color.parseColor("#1c7900"));
                }           
                } else {
                this.findViewById(i).setBackgroundColor(
                        Color.parseColor("#1c7900"));           
                }       
        }

    }
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: its a project too big code

Comment: am asking particular acitivity code

Comment: post the code where you initialize the buttons in the activity and its listeners. The issue should be there

Answer (score 2):

Take three `RadioButtons` and put them inside a `RadioGroup` and make them look like a button by setting a selector as background. So at a time only one will be selected and get highlighted.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

This way you will not need to handle the change and color manually.

Comment: its not radio button

Comment: but u can easily use radiobuttons (shaping them as buttons lookalike ) as normal buttons without having any headache of changing their background manually.

Comment: i cant change bcoz  by clicking on button i need to get 3 list that means for one button 3 list are attached

Comment: you have or can set an onClickListener for checkbox aswell cbx.setOnClickListener(.....); same as of button.

Comment: its not check box , actually 3 lists attached to one button top list  bottom button are there if i click another button it wil load another 3 list views

Answer (score 0):

Initially keep all the buttons green.Keep track of previous clicked button.

```
int previousbutton = 0;
```

then in onclick:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if(previousbutton != 0){
        findViewById(previousbutton).setBackgroundColor(//set green color);
    }
        v.setBackgroundColor(//set red color);
        previousbutton = v.getId();
}
```

Comment: i cant keep all buttons green bcoz for top list views bottom buttons are atta ced unfortunatelly 3 list views automatically appear so one already in red and remainong two in green. those are horizotally scroling buttons but visible outside  only 3

Comment: u mean to say initially one button is red as it is already selected and the other two are green?

Comment: yes that what i want and not only that when on single selectinmg of button list is not loading immeadiatly it is taking delay if clicking another button

Comment: First keep the color of already selected button as red and initialize previousbutton variable as previousbutton = // id of already selected button.That's it.

Comment: can please explain me in programatically

Comment: is it possible to post the screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?